# Get Elements Name with the same Input File tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem in jQuery code. I have two HTML input file code with different name. How do I get the second input file name in jQuery

Here is my HTML Code :

```
<input type="file" name="photo_a"   />
<input type="file" name="photo_b" />
```

And Here is my jQuery Code :

```
var nameElement = $('input[type=file]').attr('name');
alert(nameElement);
```

How do i get the name **photo_b**, my jquery code just get the **photo_a** name.

Please help me solve this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery `eq` to get the element by index in the selection, the selection gives both inputs, `eq(1)` selects the second one by index. Also, as per requested, use `change` event listener, when you select an image to upload, you get the file button name you selected:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


  $('input[type=file]').change(function(){
    
    
    alert($(this).attr("name"));
          
  });
  
$("#secFileName").html($('input[type=file]').eq(1).attr('name'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="photo_a"   />
<input type="file" name="photo_b" />

<br /><br />
Second File Name
<div id="secFileName"></div>
```

Comment: I've done that before, but it just only giving me the 1st or 2nd name. what i want is when i choose the first file button, it gave me the alert of photo_a, and when i choose the second file button, it gave me the alert of photo_b

Comment: I have update the snippet to use `change` event listener, when you select a image to upload, you get the file button name you selected, is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use js function for this only ?

```
document.getElementsByName("photo_b");
```

Comment: because i want to call the elements name dynamicly in my function. in case, when i choose the first file button, it gave me the alert of photo_a, and when i choose the second file button, it gave me the alert of photo_b

Answer (score 0):

You have to do

```js
//it gets current changed file name
function getName(thisObj){
  alert($(thisObj).attr("name"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="photo_a"  onchange="getName(this)" />
<input type="file" name="photo_b" onchange="getName(this)" />
```